# Removing items from one lisbox into another vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to select items from one list box, remove them and by clicking a button and inserting them to another list box. I'm stuck because it deletes items but they are not moving to the second list box.

```
Public Class frmShop
    Private Sub frmShop_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.BackColor = Color.LightGray

        With lstStock.Items
            .Add("Orange Juice")
            .Add("Pepper")
            .Add("Ham")
            .Add("Butter")
            .Add("Eggs")
            .Add("Bread")
            .Add("Tea")
            .Add("Coffee")
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        lstStock.Items.Add(txtAdd.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnMoveOver_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMoveOver.Click
        lstStock.Items.RemoveAt(lstStock.SelectedIndex)
        lstBasket.Items.Add(lstStock.SelectedIndex)

        If lstStock.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You must select an item", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: They don't move to the second listbox because you have not written the code that adds the removed item to the second listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not moving the item of the ListBox.

You can use the following solution on the `btnMoveOver` instead of your current code:

```
Private Sub btnMoveOver_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMoveOver.Click

    If lstStock.SelectedItems.Count < 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You must select an item", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    lstBasket.Items.Add(lstStock.Items(lstStock.SelectedIndex))
    lstStock.Items.RemoveAt(lstStock.SelectedIndex)
End Sub
```

You can also support the users of your application with the following code:

```
Private Sub lstStock_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstStock.SelectedValueChanged
    btnMoveOver.Enabled = CBool(lstStock.Items.Count > 0)
End Sub
```

With this event the button get disabled in case there are no more items on the ListBox of the stock.

---

A solution using [`SelectedIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `if` statement:

```
Private Sub btnMoveOver_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMoveOver.Click

    If lstStock.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You must select an item", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    lstBasket.Items.Add(lstStock.Items(lstStock.SelectedIndex))
    lstStock.Items.RemoveAt(lstStock.SelectedIndex)
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, your solution works, for that part. Can you give me hint how to create if statement when there are no more items in stock list box

Comment: In my, if statement when I remove the item from the stock list and insert to the basket I get a message "You must select an item" any chance you can explain why is that? Sorry for asking but I would like to understand what is wrong?

Comment: Your selected item was removed so there is no selected item (-1) on the if statement. If you move the if statement to the top of the button event it should work, but you have to make sure to exit the sub in case there is no item.

Comment: I see now because If I don't the ArgumentOutOfRangeException appears. Thank you.

Comment: Last question if you don't mind. How can we make if statement using selectedIndex instead of selectedItems. Can we using try - catch exception for that?

Comment: offtopic: Too bad your blog is only in German, would love to read. Thanks a million.